# in windows 7 .bat file can one get the long filename from a short one

Tags: windows, batch-file

specifically in a batch file in windows 7 one can use the line

set MYDIR=%~dps0%

to get the directory path containing the batch file.

On the windows 7 machine it contains generated 8.3 names for elements of the path.

Is there a way to get the "long filename" version of this path? from within a ".bat" file ??

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `s`.

```
set MYDIR=%~dp0
```

From `for /?`:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

Comment: Of course the one they are missing is:

"- expanded path contains full long file names when they differ from the short version"

Comment: I will try getting rid of the s and see

Comment: Ok I tried getting rid of the s on my windows 7 box and using %~dp0% instead of %~dps0%   and it still gives the short version of the over 8.3 directories in the path. Oh how we love windows :)